# Resize TabPage in TabControl

Tags: c#, resize, tabpage

I'm building a small GUI with a TabControl and different TabPages. At the moment i try to understand what goes wrong with the windowsize of my TabPages. Into the Visual Studio designer i have the full size, but when i'm running the program, any of my TabPages are totally resized ... 
I also tried to set some properties, but anything works ...

[image]

It would be nice, if someone have a solution :D .. i'm pretty new with it..

Comment: It looks as if the TabControl not the TabPage is resized. TabPage will always fill the tab control..

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the TabControl... which property is explaining this behaviour? :/ i have no idea

Comment: you need to set either Dock or Anchor (not both at the same time)

Comment: @Bizhan that solved it. i used both properties and organized other form elements in a different way. Thank you !

Comment: Dock and Anchor can modify the size. But of course you can write ode that will change size as well. Look for all! If the Anchor is top and bottom and you then make the form higher it will grow but if you make it less high it will shrink.